# setting font attributes in formulas in Crystal Reports

Tags: html, crystal-reports

I want to show a field on a report in italics, but have certain words, if they occur, in bold italics (or just bold.)

I don't seem to be able to do this.  I can do it the other way around, like this:   "< b>Bold and < i>italic text." (the sentence is bold and the word italic is bold and in italics.)  But if I do what I am trying to do:  "< i>Italic and  < b>bold text." - it is all just italics.   Is there a way to do this?

(I have deliberately put the spaces into the tags while posting this question so the tags are not interpreted here.  In Crystal, I obviously don't have these spaces.)
Thanks

Comment: If bold tag is inside a italic tag then whole tag will be italic.. what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want the entire text in italics, with certain words within it to be bold (as well as italics.)